# Connecting to Splunk with Javascript but not getting my saved searches

Tags: javascript, splunk

I am trying to get some information out of Splunk so I can play with it.  I am successful on my login, but then I am not able to do anything.  I have tried to get my saved searches and jobs to no avail.  Here is my code that I use to login and try to get the saved searches.

```
var splunkjs = require('splunk-sdk');
    var service = new splunkjs.Service({username: "****", password: "*****", host: "dllprdspl01.dl.prd.p.******.com", port: 8089, scheme: "https", version: 5});
    service.login(function(err, success) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log("Login was successful: " + success);
        var mySavedSearches = service.savedSearches();
        mySavedSearches.fetch(function(err, mySavedSearches) {
          console.log("There are " + mySavedSearches.list().length + " saved searches");
          var savedSearchColl = mySavedSearches.list();
          for(var i = 0; i < savedSearchColl.length; i++) {
            var search = savedSearchColl[i];
            console.log(i + ": " + savedSearchColl[i].name);
            console.log("    Query: " + savedSearchColl[i].properties().search + "\n");
          }
        });
    });
```

I come back successful on the login, but when I try to list my saved searches, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'list' of undefined
```

After I log in I have printed my service to the console and I dont see anything that seems wrong.

I have been able to connect and get a session key with the following code:

```
var splunkjs = require('splunk-sdk');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var context = new splunkjs.Context({username: "****", password: "****", host: "****.com", port: 8089, scheme: "https", version: 5});
var sessionKey;
var key = context.login(function(err, success){
  if(err){
    throw err;
  }
  // console.log("Login was successful " + success);
  var keyXml = key.req.res.body;
  var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
  parser.parseString(keyXml, function(err, result){
    sessionKey = result.response.sessionKey[0];
  });
  context.sessionKey = sessionKey;
  console.log(context);
  context.get('services/saved/searches/hamm_test_mn7', function(err, response){
    console.get(response);
  })
});
```

If I can get my session key, then I should be logged in to splunk.  How would I go about from there to complete my saved searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through the help of Neeraj, who works at Splunk, I was able to connect to Splunk and get my saved searches.  I did not notice that I had to install xml2json on my Splunk server.  Here is the [doc](http://dev.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAAEFN) page to explain all that needs to happen.  I then had to change my version number to 4.3 instead of 5 like above.  Everything then connected and I was able to get my saved searches like I wanted.  With the original code it appeared that I was connecting, but really I was being returned an empty service object.  Here is the code I used to make sure I was connecting.  When you see the session key, then you know that Splunk is talking back to you.

```
var splunkjs = require('splunk-sdk');
var service = new splunkjs.Service({username: "admin",password: "changeme",host: "localhost",port:8089,scheme: "https",version: 4.3});
service.login(function (err, success) {
    if (err) console.log("Error logging in", err);
    else console.log(service.sessionKey);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is surprising that you can login but it chokes on saved searches. How about we see if an error is thrown during fetching. Try the following code and let me know if you see anything in the console.

```
var splunkjs = require('splunk-sdk');
var service = new splunkjs.Service({username: "****", password: "*****", host: "dllprdspl01.dl.prd.p.******.com", port: 8089, scheme: "https", version: 5});
service.login(function(err, success) {
  if (err) {
      throw err;
  }
  console.log("Login was successful: " + success);
  var mySavedSearches = service.savedSearches();
  mySavedSearches.fetch(function(err, mySavedSearches) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error in fetching savedSearches:", err);
      throw err;
    }
    console.log("There are " + mySavedSearches.list().length + " saved searches");
    var savedSearchColl = mySavedSearches.list();
    for(var i = 0; i < savedSearchColl.length; i++) {
      var search = savedSearchColl[i];
      console.log(i + ": " + savedSearchColl[i].name);
      console.log("    Query: " + savedSearchColl[i].properties().search + "\n");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Here is the error that I get (I wish I could format it better) `Error in fetching savedSearches: { response: 
   { headers: 
      { connection: 'close',
        'content-length': '100',
        'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        date: 'Mon, 10 Dec 2012 14:18:59 GMT',
        server: 'Splunkd' },
     statusCode: 401 },
  status: 401,
  data: '<response>\n<messages>\n<msg type="WARN">call not properly authenticated</msg>\n</messages>\n</response>',
  error: null }`

Comment: It almost looks like your credentials are incorrect but for some reason it doesn't tell you that until the savedSearches call. Let's try a few things:
1) Confirm the credentials by logging in from the browser.
2) You are passing in a Splunk version of 5. Your output (XML) seems to indicate that you don't have 5. Confirm the Splunk version.

Comment: 3) Finally, try the following code
`var splunkjs = require('splunk-sdk');
var service = new splunkjs.Service({username: "***", password: "***", host: "***", port: ***, scheme: "https", version: 5});
service.login(function(err, success) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error logging in", err);
  }
  console.log(service.sessionKey);
});`

Comment: I tried the code and the return message was `Login failed`.  I realized that I am running 4.3.4, so I changed the version, but still got an error of `404 - not found`.  I just attached to the main question code that I was able to run to get a session key.  Maybe that will help you point me in the right direction.

Comment: @jhamm - If you have more code to share, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13753775/edit). Do not append broken/non-working code to one of the "answers".

Comment: @jhamm - Maybe we can take this offline and post the final answer once we are able to resolve it. Email me at nluthra@splunk.com